# Reading resources from src/main/resources/.. in spring-MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a question that makes my head ache.
First, my project structure looks like below.
[image]

I made a controller, which returns image(*.png) file to the appropriate request.

The code of controller is written below.

```java
@Controller
public class ImageController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/ImageStore.do", produces = MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody byte[] getStoreImage(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
        String image_name = request.getParameter("image_name");
        Resource resource = null;
        try {
            resource = new ClassPathResource("/images/stores/" + image_name);
            if(resource == null) {
                throw new NullPointerException();
            }
        } catch(NullPointerException e) {
            resource = new ClassPathResource("/images/stores/noimage.png");
        }
        InputStream inputStream = resource.getInputStream();
        return IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
    }
}
```

Q1. I added `try-catch` phrase to send `noimage.png` if the request parameter is wrong, or if the filename of request parameter `image_name` does not exist. But it doesn't seem to work, and it gives me log saying
`class path resource [images/stores/noima.png] cannot be opened because it does not exist`
(If you need to know the full stack trace, I will comment below.)

Q2. I have 2 image files, `hello.png` and `noimage.png` in the folder `/resources/images/stores/`. I can read `noimage.png` correctly, but if I make request `localhost:8080/ImageStore.do?image_name=hello.png`, then it makes an error, making the same log in Q1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason to think that the constructor would result in a `null` value.

The exception you are getting is likely from the `getInputStream` method, which is [documented](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ClassPathResource.html#getInputStream--) to throw

> FileNotFoundException - if the underlying resource doesn't exist
>
> IOException - if the content stream could not be opened

A slight adjustment might help

```
@Controller
public class ImageController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/ImageStore.do", produces = MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody byte[] getStoreImage(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            String image_name = request.getParameter("image_name");
            is = new ClassPathResource("/images/stores/" + image_name).getInputStream();
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            is = new ClassPathResource("/images/stores/noimage.png").getInputStream();
        }

        return IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
    }
}
```

You should include the stack trace, and exception message, which might assist understanding your second query, but I would check that the file really does exist, with the exact name you're using.

Comment: First of all, thank you @ptomli for replying. I tried it, and it didn't seem to solve my problem. If you see the picture my project structure  above, you can see that there are `hello.png` and `noimage.png` under `/resources/images/stores/`. If I make request `localhost:8080/ImageStore.do?image_name=hello.png`, it shows me the correct image, but if I make `localhost:8080/ImageStore.do?image_name=noimage.png`, it shows me FileNotFoundException page. Is it possible that spring cannot read more than 1 files from the resources folder?

Comment: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [images/events/noimage.png] cannot be opened because it does not exist`.

Comment: Your last comment here is showing an error finding a file in the `events` sub-directory, which suggests that the code that generated the error is not the same code as we're looking at above.

Comment: Yeah but if the `events` sub-directory is wrong, it should fail to reed `hello.png` file as well,,

Comment: I solved the problem by refactoring the name of  `noimage.png` to `default.png`. It seems like the name `noimage` is some kind of reserved-word or something :)  Thanks for your help!